# Does one of these exchanges have a sandbox to test?

Tags: exchanges, testing

I want to test some trading. Does Binance, Bittrex, Poloniex, Kraken or Gemini have a sandbox to trade fake crypto to test systems?

Comment: Did you check their websites?! I use gdax and they have it documented, and that's what I would look into.

Comment: I checked polo and they had nothing obviously as far as I could find but then someone told me polo has a sandbox so I figured I would ask here.

Comment: If you have an account with them, I would ask them through a support request.

Answer (score 0):

I work for an exchange, I don't know if I am allowed to say which, but have something called a test net, which is similar to what you are describing and which many people use to test trading strategies.